# Navbar brand text only clickable once, after it locks and cant be clicked again

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Lets say that i have a navbar with a brand text and 3 links like so:

**PetesPCworld** | Hardware | Software | Support |

*Using this example:* If i click on lets say "Hardware" then everything is okay, i can use the Brand text (PetesPCworld) to go back to the home page, but if i do this once again, lets say i click on the "Hardware" again, then i cant go back to the homepage using the Brand text.

And by default you start at the home page (duh..)

**HTML CODE:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Peter">
        <title>Számítógépes Hardver</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main-style/main-style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <!-- W A R N I N G !!!! ---------------   W A R N I N G !!!! -->

    <!-- This is basically a school project, and in no way i'm a professional ! -->

    <!-- Oh boi, this is some fine spaghet.. -->

    <body>
        <div id="nav-container" class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">

                <!-- I think the problem is here with this <a> tag. -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Számítógépes Hardver</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

                  <ul class="navbar-nav  nav">


                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#MOBOandCPU" data-toggle="tab">Alaplapok, CPU</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#Memory-Types" data-toggle="tab">Memóriák</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bővítőkártyák</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Monitorok</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nyomtatók</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lapolvasók</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Háttértárak</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kábelek</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mutató Eszközök</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Multimédiás eszközök</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hordozható Adattárolók</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Elavult Technológiák</a>
                    </li>

                  </ul>

                </div>  
            </nav>
        </div>
          


        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
              <div id="header-container" class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
                <h2 id="header">Számítógépes Hardver</h2>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="MOBOandCPU">
                <p>dancing polish cow</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="Memory-Types">
                <p>dancing ukranian toilet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```css
#nav-container{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#header{
    padding: 1%;
}

#header-container{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe be a bit more specific with what you mean by "After that it just gives up"?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Is the issue that the navbar brand is only clickable once? Or do you want it to be clickable once?